# Prove basis for product topology is collection of all sets with finitely many factors restricted to open sets

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Prove a basis for the product topology on $\prod_{a \in \lambda}X_{a}$ is the collection of all sets of the form $\prod_{a \in \lambda}U_a$ where $U_a$ is open in $X_a$ for each $a$ and $U_a=X_a$ for all but finitely many $a$. Given that the product topology is defined as the topology generated by the subbasis $S=\bigcup\limits_{B \in \lambda}S_B$. Where $S_B=\{\pi_B^{-1}(U_B)|U_B \ \ \text{open in}\ \ X_B \}$

Attempt:Let $S=\bigcup\limits_{B \in Y}S_B$ be a subbasis for the product topology, where $S_B=
\{ \pi^{-1}_{B}(U_B)|U_{B} \ \ \text{open in}\ \ X_B \}$. Then each of the factors of elements of $S$ are of the form $U_a=X_a$ for all $a \neq B$ and $U_B$ for $B \in Y$.So only one factor is not necessarily equal to $X_a$. Then a basis element is a finite intersection of subbasis elements $\pi^{-1}_i(U_i)$ where $i=i_1,...,i_k$. So $U_a=X_a$ for all $i\neq i_1,...,i_k$.

Comment: It seems like the answer to that uestion depends highly on how you define the product topology. Some books even define it as the topology generated by the basis that you wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's essentially the idea: more succinctly:

(standard fact about bases and subbases): if $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase, then the set of finite intersection of elements from $\mathcal{S}$ form a base.

A finite intersection from $\mathcal{S}$ looks like $\pi_{a_1}^{-1}[U_1] \cap \pi_{a_2}^{-1}[U_2] \ldots \cap \pi_{a_n}^{-1}[U_n]$, where $a_1, \ldots a_n$ form a finite subset of $\lambda$ (all distinct, because we can use $p_a^{-1}[U] \cap \pi_a^{-1}[V]= \pi_a^{-1}[U \cap V]$ to take sets with the same projection together, a minor point that you omitted) and this is just the set $$\prod_{a \in \lambda} O_a$$ where $O_a = U_i$ if $a = a_i$ for some $i \in \{1,\ldots n\}$ (the finite exception set) and $O_a = X_a$ otherwise. So these form exactly the base you had to prove to be a base: it's just the standard base from the subbase.